# Saving JavaList to Cassandra table using spark context

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Hi I am very new to spark and scala, Here I am facing some issue with saving data into cassandra below is my scenario

1) I get list of user defined objects (say User Objects which contains firstName, lastName etc..) from my java class to scala class and upto here its fine I am able to access User Object and able to print its contents

2) Now I want to save that usersList into cassandra table using spark context, I have gone through many examples but every where I see creating **Seq** with our **caseClass** and hardcoded values and then saving to cassandra, I have tried that and working fine for me as below

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import java.util.ArrayList

object SparkCassandra extends App {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
        .setMaster("local[*]")
        .setAppName("SparkCassandra")
        //set Cassandra host address as your local address
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
     val usersList = Test.getUsers
     usersList.foreach(x => print(x.getFirstName))
    val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(userTable("testName1"), userTable("testName1")))
    collection.saveToCassandra("demo", "user", SomeColumns("name"))
    sc.stop()
}

case class userTable(name: String)
```

But here my requirement is to use dynamic values from my usersList instead of hardcoaded values, or any other way to achieve this.

Comment: How many users? Where are these values stored?

Comment: There will be upto 20k Users, actullay I get that list from some other javaClass and need to store in cassandra table

Comment: As long as you are parallelizing, it should work. How about creating a Seq which contains all case class objects of "userTable" from "usersList" and parallelize and save it?

Comment: It would be easy if you can post the error to see what is exactly going wrong.

Comment: @Sreekar I am not getting any error, I am finding way to insert that list data to cassandra table what every way it may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution for my requirement tested and working fine as below:

**My Scala Code:**

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns
import com.datastax.spark.connector.toNamedColumnRef
import com.datastax.spark.connector.toRDDFunctions

object JavaListInsert {
  def randomStores(sc: SparkContext, users: List[User]): RDD[(String, String, String)] = {
       sc.parallelize(users).map { x => 
       val fistName = x.getFirstName
       val lastName = x.getLastName
       val city = x.getCity
       (fistName, lastName, city)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("cassandraInsert")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val usersList = Test.getUsers.toList
    randomStores(sc, usersList).
      saveToCassandra("test", "stores", SomeColumns("first_name", "last_name", "city"))
    sc.stop
  }
}
```

**Java Pojo Object:**

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
    public class User implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -187292417543564400L;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String city;

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }
}
```

**Java Class to return List of Users:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {
    public static List<User> getUsers() {
        ArrayList<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
        for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setFirstName("firstName_+"+i);
            user.setLastName("lastName_+"+i);
            user.setCity("city_+"+i);
            usersList.add(user);
        }
        return usersList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `RDD` of `CassandraRow` objects, you can directly save the result without having to specify columns or case classes. In addition, `CassandraRow` has the hugely convenient `fromMap` function, so you can define your rows as `Map` objects, convert them, and save the result.

Example:

```
val myData = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Map("name" -> "spiffman", "address" -> "127.0.0.1"),
    Map("name" -> "Shabarinath", "address" -> "127.0.0.1")
  )
)

val cassandraRowData = myData.map(rowMap => CassandraRow.fromMap(rowMap))

cassandraRowData.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")
```

Comment: thanx for reply, Here my requirement is not to use hardcoded  values in place of "spiffman" and "shabarinath" I need to use the list object values

Comment: What is the type of the list object? Can you convert it to a Map?

Comment: List of Simple pojo User object which contains firstname and getters and setters and I want to store that list

Comment: I mean what is the output type of `Test.getUsers`? If it's a `Seq[String]` of the user names, you could do `sc.parallelize(Test.getUsers.map(user => CassandraRow.fromMap(Map("name" -> user)).saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")`for example.

Comment: output of getUsers is List<Users> (java.util.list)

Comment: You're really making it difficult to help... How am I supposed to know what a `Users` type is? What are the fields you want to store? What is your table schema? At this point I think you need to figure out how to transform your java objects into a Scala `Map` object and then modify my solution above to fit your application... If that's not trivial then you need to explain why, in detail, and what you've tried.